# Is there a way to detect if a loop has stopped in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to detect when my loop has stopped so that i could use an if statement saying: if "the loop has stopped": `print(text)`

Code:

```
faces = detector(gray)

for face in faces:

    x, y = face.left(), face.top()
    x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
    rectangle = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    if "the loop has stopped":
        cv2.putText(frame, "Asleep", (50, 150), font, 7, (0, 0, 255))
```

Comment: Adding a print AFTER the loop doesn't do the job?

Comment: When the for loop terminates, execution will resume with the next statement after the loop. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why do you need a signal when the loop *stops*? `if "the loop has stopped":` is **in** the loop so it certainly won't be stopped when that statement has been reached.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for ... else` construct for your specific use case. It looks like

`for` loops also have an `else` clause which most of us are unfamiliar with. The `else` clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did not encounter a `break` statement. They are really useful once you understand where to use them. I, myself, came to know about them a lot later.

The common construct is to run a loop and search for an item. If the item is found, we break out of the loop using the break statement. There are two scenarios in which the loop may end. The first one is when the item is found and `break` is encountered. The second scenario is that the loop ends without encountering a break statement. Now we may want to know which one of these is the reason for a loop’s completion. One method is to set a flag and then check it once the loop ends. Another is to use the else clause.

This is the basic structure of a for/else loop:

```
for item in container:
    if search_something(item):
        # Found it!
        process(item)
        break
else:
    # Didn't find anything..
```

Comment: the peoblem here is that I am useing x and y positions (position of the face) so i cant really know the value. And as soon as it doesnt detect a face, it just stopps at the last coordinates. Therefore I need to know when the loop stopps detecting coordinates so I can tell it to write the text

Comment: Props for bringing to light this often-overlooked Python feature!  But I think the case in question here is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have said in comments, once the `for` loop has been through every `face` in `faces` it will carry on executing code. You don't need to do anything special to make it stop looping, unless you have a reason to break out of that process earlier (before it has been through every `face`).

So you just need to un-indent the statement at the end.

I think you probably want this:

```py
faces = detector(gray)

for face in faces:
    x, y = face.left(), face.top()
    x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
    rectangle = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# this will run after the for loop has finished
cv2.putText(frame, "Asleep", (50, 150), font, 7, (0, 0, 255))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't very clear in my description. My loop doesnt detect faces. It detects positions of faces. So if it detects my face, it will keep printing the x and y position of my face, and if it doesn't detect my face anymore, it will stay on the last x and y coordinates. So i need it to stop the loop after it stopps detecting coordinates so that i can print the text. Because right now the loop doesnt have an end.

Comment: So what type of object is `faces`? i.e. what does `detector()` return? And what library/package is the `detector()` function from?

Answer (score 0):

I would really appreciate it if you can post the full code/ at least the loop you are referring to in the question details.

I don't think there is a way to detect if a loop has ended or not in python.
If you want to check if a for loop went from range i to n completely without any problem then you iterator value can be checked with the (max-1) of your range function. if the for loop has break statement in between somewhere or any other issues causing the loop to terminate abruptly the iterators value would be lesser than (max-1) of your range function

Answer (score 0):

This can be done; but it’s not clear why you would want to.

If there was a strong reason to detect the state of the loop while in the loop, you could avoid using a `for` loop and iterate manually by converting the iterable (faces) to an iterator via the `iter` function. You’ll know when the iterator is concluded — when you call `next`, you’ll get a `StopIteration` exception.

A `for` loop is just syntactic sugar for that operation — a lot easier to work with.

I’m curious why you want to do this instead of just letting the `for` loop conclude and doing what you need on the line after the loop.

Comment: My loop doesn't detect faces. It detects positions of faces. So if it detects my face, it will keep printing the x and y position of my face, and if it doesn't detect my face anymore, it will stay on the last x and y coordinates. So i need it to stop the loop after it stopps detecting coordinates so that i can print the text. Because right now the loop doesn't have an end.

Comment: You are iterating over the content of `faces`. Unless that iterable object is growing while the `for` loop is running (which is not happening from the code you posted), then then loop runs once for each face in `faces` then stops. You don’t have a separate loop for positions. You can either leave the loop early via a `break` or you can let the loop finish once it has visited every element of `faces`. That’s all that loop will do. How do you think the concept of positions of faces relates to your code?